# Data is vanished in next line

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Can anyone please explain me what is happened in these codes and how can I solve it?

I get the data in the parent's `mounted` function and update its data. So I have the new object in the child. But the value of the property of this object is empty!

Parent:

```
<template>
    <div class="main-page">
        <main-content v-bind:config="mainContentConfig" />
    </div>
</template>
mounted(){
    fetchData().then(editions => { editions.sort((e1, e2) => e1.name.toLowerCase().localeCompare(e2.name.toLowerCase()))
        this.mainContentConfig.intranetEditions = [...editions];
        this.mainContentConfig.currentMenuIndex = 1;
    });
}
```

Child:

```
mounted(){
    console.log("AA==============>", this.config);
    console.log("BB==============>", this.config.intranetEditions);
}
```

But on the console I have:

[image]

I found this problem when I fill other data in the child class with `this.config.intranetEditions` array which always is empty!

**Edit:**
I tried this code too, but no difference!

```
[...this.config.intranetEditions]
```

**Edit 2** This code tested too, but nothing!

```
console.log("AA==============>", this.config);
console.log("BB==============>", JSON.stringify(this.config.intranetEditions));
```

Comment: console logs of objects/arrays can be misleading - try `console.log("AA==============>", JSON.stringify(this.config));` and similar for the next line

Comment: what is your vue version?
try to read this: https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-nextTick
I think it would be solve your problem with reactivity

Answer (score 1):

The child-component is mounted but the parent fetch is not finished yet, so `this.config` is an observer until the fetch is done (so the `then` is fired) and the var fulfilled.

Can you try to watch the prop `config` in the child-component? then you will see when `this.config` is fulfilled.

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers

**UPDATE WITH EXAMPLE:**

child-component

```
watch: {
  config(newValue) {
    console.log("AA==============>", newValue.intranetEditions);
    checkConfigValue();
  },
},

methods: {
  checkConfigValue() {
    console.log("BB==============>", this.config.intranetEditions);
  };
},
```

So you can wether do something in the watcher with the `newValue`, or trigger a method and use `this.config`. Both consoles, will print the same in this case.