# How to update child after rest api call in parent?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am a react.js developer and currently working with vue.js. May react.js viewpoint confused me or maybe I am not good at the vue.js yet. Could you please help me with this problem:

(As I do in react) I have a root element that is responsible for communicating with the server and manage data and spread them to the children. This will continue until the last child in this tree gets its data. But the problem is that with updating the data in the parent its children can not inform about to. So I use some watcher and a key to force to update and function to handle this watcher. My question is that is this really hard to work like this in vue.js or I do it in the wrong way?

My parent component is this:

```
<template>
    <div class="main-page">
        <left-sidebar v-bind:config="allIntranetEditions" />
        <main-content v-bind:config="mainContentConfig" :key="runIndex" />
    </div>
</template>
....
data(){
            return {
                currentIntranetEditions: [],
                allIntranetEditions: [],
                mainContentConfig:{
                    sharedContents: []
                },
                runIndex: 0
            }
        },
        mounted(){
            IntranetResource.fetch().then(editions => {
                editions.sort((e1, e2) => e1.name.toLowerCase().localeCompare(e2.name.toLowerCase()))
                this.allIntranetEditions = editions;
                this.currentIntranetEditions = editions;
            });
        },
        watch: {
            currentIntranetEditions: {
                handler: function(){
                    this.refreshSharedContent()
                }
            },
            mainContentConfig:{
                handler: function(){
                    console.log(this.mainContentConfig);
                    this.runIndex++
                }
            }
        },
        methods:{
            refreshSharedContent(){
                MainPageResources.getSharedContents(this.currentIntranetEditions).then(response => {
                    console.log("=====>", response)
                    this.mainContentConfig = {
                        sharedContents: response.data.sharedContentItemDtos
                    }
                })
            }
        }

...
```

Here a get some data and send them to my first component left-sidebar, but after getting them left sidebar doesn't work and I should put a key and a watcher and updated that key to update them!

And again for updating my other component which use the first api's result as the parameter, I should have all of this codes again for it.

In react by using hooks I just have a assign statement in the mount and doen!

My question as related to my this post:

[Data is vanished in next line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63934276/data-is-vanished-in-next-line)

Comment: Usually there is no need for watchers. As the problem is related to child components not updating, you should probably add some code of child components...

Comment: After I read your previous post and the concept about key changing, it seems you misunderstand about `mounted` hook function. The `mounted` hook function will run only once when Vue mount element into document (when the key changed Vue also create the new element so it will run again).  You shouldn't expect all data available at `mounted` but you can keep tracking by using `updated` or use watcher. But mostly you only have to declare props on child component and update data on parent component.

Comment: @Michal Levý What code should I add? I am looking for two days on the internet for a sample of how to rest API works in vue.js to update children, but all samples work on the parent and not children.

Comment: @User28 Thanks for your time. I have no changes unless the first data loading in this step. So I put this data in the mounted to initial the component. But I should manage keys(to change them to force vue.js re-render my code) to handle it if I want to don't use watcher. But in the next level of children, I have a problem with updating it again.

Comment: You should add code about your children component which are `left-sidebar` and `main-content` since the problem maybe caused by that.

Comment: @User28 what is your mean of "add code about your children component"? I don't know what code should I add where...

Comment: As the other has answered in your previous post. Vue will call `mounted` hook before your `fetch` finish. Could you explain more about how you determine that child component not update, you use word _not inform_ and _doesn't work_  which not much clear.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221686/discussion-between-user-28-and-siamak-ferdos).